# Automatically extract a bibitem in LaTex

Tags: latex

I am writing a conference paper in which I am required to use the format **\bibitem** entries rather than a BibTeX file for the references. Google Scholar support **BibTeX**. Is there an automatic method or a tool to extract **\bibitem**?

**Example:** 
I have the references in BibTeX format as follow:

```
 @article{rieck2011similarity,
  title={Similarity measures for sequential data},
  author={Rieck, Konrad},
  journal={Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery},
  volume={1},
  number={4},
  pages={296--304},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

and I want to convert BibTeX format into the following format (\bibitem):

```
\bibitem{rieck2011similarity} K.~Rieck, \emph{Similarity measures for sequential data},\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery, 2011.
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific in terms of what you want? That is, show what you currently have, and what you want to have happen.

Comment: @ Werner plz find the updates in the question above.

Comment: Perhaps this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124874/converting-to-bibitem-in-latex can help you.

Answer (score 17):

Since there is no other answer, this (not exactly automatic) way could be helpful :

- Create a *.tex file with your bibliography in BibTeX
- Compile as usual (latex/bibtex/latex)
- In the directory of the *.tex file, open the *.bbl : all citations are converted in bibitem.
- Copy/paste in your document

Source : http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2005-10/msg00552.html

Answer (score 15):

I created this [online bibtex converter](https://asouqi.github.io/bibtex-converter/), so it could convert your BibTeX text or file to bibitem.

**Example**:

```
 @article{rieck2011similarity,
  title={Similarity measures for sequential data},
  author={Rieck, Konrad},
  journal={Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery},
  volume={1},
  number={4},
  pages={296--304},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

**BibItem output**

```
\bibitem{rieck2011similarity}Rieck, K. Similarity measures for sequential data. {\em Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining And Knowledge Discovery}. \textbf{1}, 296--304 (2011)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I used this matlab function to convert it automatically one by one, its more easy to get the job done. You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/eng-suhail/Bibtex2bibitem), and here is the matlab function as the following.

```
function [bibitem] = bibtex2bibitem(bibtexpath)
path = bibtexpath;
cells = importdata(path);
A = string(cells);
n = length(cells);
K_name = strings(n,1);
citecode = extractBetween(A(1),'{',',');

for i = 2:1:n-1
        rawleft = extractBefore(A(i),'=');
        K_name(i) = strtrim(rawleft);

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        if strcmp(K_name(i),"author")
            SVacI(1) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                author = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                author = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end 

%--------------------------------------------------------------------         
        elseif strcmp(K_name(i),"title")
            SVacI(2) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                title = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                title = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end 

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        elseif strcmp(K_name(i),"journal")
            SVacI(3) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                journal = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                journal = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end 

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        elseif strcmp(K_name(i),"volume")
            SVacI(4) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                volume = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                volume = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        elseif (strcmp(K_name(i),"number"))||(strcmp(K_name(i),"issue"))
            SVacI(5) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                number = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                number = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        elseif strcmp(K_name(i),"pages")
            SVacI(6) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                pages = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                pages = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        elseif strcmp(K_name(i),"month")
            SVacI(7) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                month = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                month = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        elseif strcmp(K_name(i),"year")
            SVacI(8) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                year = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                year = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        elseif strcmp(K_name(i),"publisher")
            SVacI(9) = 1;
            rawright = extractAfter(A(i),'=');
            ccb = regexp(rawright,'}');     % ccb = [check curly bracket]
            if (ccb~=0)
                publisher = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'{','}'));
            else 
                publisher = strtrim(extractBetween(A(i),'=',','));
            end           

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
        else
            msg = join(["Sorry!","[", K_name(i), "]","is not being handled by the program."]);
            disp(msg)
        end
end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%               @-> Style reference term code varifications. 
%                  msg = join(["author","=",SVacI(1);...
%                              "title","=",SVacI(2);...
%                              "journal","=",SVacI(3);...
%                              "volume","=",SVacI(4);...
%                              "number","=",SVacI(5);...
%                              "pages","=",SVacI(6);...
%                              "month","=",SVacI(7);...
%                              "year","=",SVacI(8);...
%                              "publisher","=",SVacI(9)]);
%                              disp(SVacI)

              if all(SVacI(1)==0)||(SVacI(2)==0)||(SVacI(3)==0)||(SVacI(8)==0)
                  bibitem = sprintf('THE ARTICLE IS NOT CORRECT. THE AUTHOR, TITLE, JOURNAL AND YEAR SECTIONS ARE COMPULSORY! PLEASE INCLUDE THEM AND RE-RUN THE SOFTWARE:)');
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/},(%s).',citecode,author,title,journal,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/},(%s). %s.\n',citecode,author,title,journal,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/},(%s %s).',citecode,author,title,journal,month,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/},(%s %s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,month,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, %s,(%s).',citecode,author,title,journal,pages,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, %s,(%s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,pages,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, %s,(%s %s).',citecode,author,title,journal,pages,month,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, %s,(%s %s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,pages,month,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s,(%s).',citecode,author,title,journal,number,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s,(%s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,number,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s,(%s %s).',citecode,author,title,journal,number,month,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s,(%s %s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,number,month,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s, %s,(%s).',citecode,author,title,journal,number,pages,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s, %s,(%s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,number,pages,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s, %s,(%s %s).',citecode,author,title,journal,number,pages,month,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1])
                  disp("Attention! THE VOLUME HAS TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH NUMBER, PLEASE CHECK!") 
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, No.~%s, %s,(%s %s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,number,pages,month,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s,(%s).',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s,(%s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s,(%s %s).',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,month,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s,(%s %s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,month,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s, %s,(%s).',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,pages,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s, %s,(%s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,pages,year,publisher);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s, %s,(%s %s).',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,pages,month,year);
              elseif all(SVacI == [1    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1])
                  bibitem = sprintf('\\bibitem{%s} %s,``%s," {\\it %s\\/}, Vol.~%s, No.~%s, %s,(%s %s). %s.',citecode,author,title,journal,volume,number,pages,month,year,publisher);
              end 
              clipboard('copy',bibitem);
              disp('The bibitem has been copied to the clipboard!')
end
```

**Sample input:**

```
@article{hamid1969microwave,
  title={Microwave pasteurization of raw milk},
  author={Hamid, MAK and Boulanger, RJ and Tong, SC and Gallop, RA and Pereira, RR},
  journal={Journal of Microwave Power},
  volume={4},
  number={4},
  pages={272--275},
  year={1969},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

Sample Output: 

'\bibitem{hamid1969microwave} Hamid, MAK and Boulanger, RJ and Tong, SC and Gallop, RA and Pereira, RR,``Microwave pasteurization of raw milk," {\it Journal of Microwave Power\/}, Vol.~4, No.~4, 272--275,(1969). Taylor \& Francis.'
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23048359)

Comment: Now, the matlab function is active and stable to be used.